# How can I construct a random graph, which is created by adding orientation to a complete graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a complete graph on N vertices, how can I randomly orient all of its edges? I thought about starting out with `CompleteGraph[n]`, and then somehow transforming its adjancecy matrix, but I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

The simple way to do this is

```
DirectedGraph[CompleteGraph[5], "Random"]
```

[image]

---

**Old answer:**

You can use

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ RandomSample /@ List @@@ EdgeList@CompleteGraph[n]]
```

Let's break it down:

- `EdgeList` gives you the edge list
- `List @@@` is used to convert each directed edge `a <-> b` to a list of pairs `{a, b}`.  See also [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).
- `RandomSample[{a,b}]` returns `a` and `b` in random order.  See also [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html).

Then we convert them back to directed edges and construct a `Graph`.

A similar alternative:

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ RandomSample /@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the adjacency matrix is a viable solution. Let `m` be an `n*n` two-dimensional adjacency matrix for the complete graph (ones at every off-diagonal element, zeroes on the diagonal). This snippet of code should work:

```
Do[Do[{m[[i,j]],m[[j,i]]}=RandomChoice[{{0,1},{1,0}}],{i,1,j-1}],{j,2,n}]
```

The two nested `Do` functions cycle through all matrix elements where `i<j`, that is those on one side of the diagonal. As the graph was initially complete, all such elements `m[[i,j]]` were equal to 1 and had a corresponding element `m[[j,i]]` (the symetrically located one) also equal to 1. To orient a give edge we must either make `m[[i,j]]` equal to 1 and `m[[j,i]]` equal to 0 or vice versa, which is exactly what

```
{m[[i,j]],m[[j,i]]}=RandomChoice[{{0,1},{1,0}}]
```

does.

**UPD**

As Szabolcs suggests, for extra brevity (perhaps at the expense of readability for people unfamiliar with Mathematica) a shorter version of that line of code:

```
Do[{m[[i,j]],m[[j,i]]}=RandomSample[{0,1}],{j,2,n},{i,1,j-1}]
```

Comment: It's not necessary to nest `Do`.  `Do[..., {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, i-1}]` works.  `RandomChoice[{{0,1},{1,0}}]` is equivalent to `RandomSample[{0,1}]`.

Comment: Thanks for filling me in. I've always had my doubts when one iterator was dependent on the other, so I always nested the Do's, but that does indeed work (the other way round `...{j,1,i-1},{i,2,n}]` doesn't though). Nice to know any little tricks that get a line of code even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 8;
u = UpperTriangularize[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 1];
am = u + LowerTriangularize[1 - Transpose@u, -1]; 
AdjacencyGraph[am, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: See the update to my answer for a simple way.

Comment: @Szabolcs, excellent!!